# Recursive write permissions on files and folders, with Prestashop on WAMP

Tags: windows-7, installation, permissions, wamp

I am trying to install Prestashop in Windows 7 / WAMP server. But I have a problem with it, it says:

> Recursive write permissions on files and folders: ~/sitemap.xml

I am trying this:

> Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from
>   this object checkbox must be checked when changing permissions under
>   Properties > Security tab > Advanced > Change Permission Do this in
>   the GUI to the parent folder

but, when I click the "ok"...the checkbox will be unchecked again and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Run `cmd` as Administrator.

Type command:

```
takeown /F "C:\YourFolderName\*" /R /A /D Y
```

Reset permission:

```
icacls "C:\YourFolderName\*" /T /Q /C /RESET
```

Comment: It doesn't work :S

Comment: @Renegade8 update

Comment: I tried, nothing happens. All users have "full acces" but when I want to install the prestashop, I have the same problem:
Recursive write permissions on files and folders: ~/sitemap.xml

Comment: stop wamp server?

Comment: I stop all services and tried the takeown/icacls commands. Still nothing.